# Excel formula for weighting scores

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm an excel novice. I have a team of staff who are individually scoring application forms.  To account for biases, I would like to weight some of their scores depending on how far they depart from the overall mean. Is there a way (I'm sure there is!) of getting Excel to calculate the overall mean, then the mean for that scorer, calculating the difference between the two, and adding (if they've been overly strict) or subtracting (if they've been overly generous) the difference to create a new weighted value for that item?

Thanks for you help. Jon

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this, but I don’t think you’ll find this to be the right place for what you need.  SE is intended for people trying to solve a problem using excel and have a specific question about how something works, or why what they are trying didn’t work.  What you are asking for is more like design work and well beyond the scope of Super User.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your table?

Comment: Agreed with @MaxR, you can do this, but is the mean the "true" value you want to correct to? What if all of your raters were overly strict? If I remember most literature looking at inter-rater reliability, the focus was on training prior to rating, with retraining/recalibration done during the rating process. Now if your ratings have already been done and you are certain this is the correction you want, then using a couple of `AVERAGEIFS` should get you there.